# Cannot connect to the Internet using a DSL router in a Cyberam secured network

Tags: internet, wireless-router

I have this Cyberoam-secured network in my college dorm. When connecting to internet using a PC or a Laptop, you just attatch the Ethernet wire to it, you get a login page in a browser, you enter the login credentials and you are connected to the Internet.

Now, I'm trying to have that very Ethernet connection via a DSL Router. I've this Netgear JNR1010 DSL router. I chose to get IP addresses and DNS addresses dynamically from the ISP. The router's status page shows internet to be connected and in good condition but I can't really access Internet anyway.

[image: Internet Port]

[image: Connection Statistics]

[image: Connection Status]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured, it was because my college's network was using `192.168.1.*` IPs and my router's IP was configured the same. Changing the router's IP to `192.168.0.1` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your routers connection type manually from Dynamic to PPoE for password authentication. Give it a try and if it fails comment back.

Comment: No it doesn't work at all. Please see the question update; things look good when I choose to retrieve IP addresses and DNS server addresses dynamically. But I cannot get to the internet nor the Cyberroam login page.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any sign of a PPPoE status.I'll give a link to the routers manual, pay special attention to pages 20 & 21.It is your router that must first establish the passworded connection before your computer.In other words you should not see the login screen because your router is supposed to authenticate before you. Your connection may be established, but you are not authenticated. If your router's page differs a bit from the manual, check around a bit to see if the option is somewhere else.[routers manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/JNR1010/JNR1010_UM_10Aug12.pdf)

Comment: Also, it occurred to me that my router's setup may be quite different from yours, I apologize if I may have caused confusion in switching type from dynamic to PPPoE. It looks as if yours may have a sub-group option instead.

Comment: If that fails, you may want to try "bridge mode" or any options that may turn your router into a repeater. If successful this will mean you need to log in on your computer again.

Comment: I still can't get through. Seems like PPPoE isn't gonna work. And I'm afraid that there is no Bridge mode in this model. ANd as of repeating, there is only Wireless Repeating feature available.

Comment: Another thing, when I use **Detect type of internet connection** feature of the router, it says that I have a **Static IP connection**. But all I have been provided with is the username and password to the Cyberoam login. :\

Comment: Hmmm... we're running out of options with this particular router......If PPPoE/entering the username & password options are not available inside router configuration for this connection it may not be able to connect/transmit data to additional computers at all. I'm stumped for now, I'll let you know if I think of anything else that might help. There is always that possibility that it might still be something stupid we haven't noticed.

Comment: Also if you have a network cable lying around I would try hooking it up directly to the router to see if there is a possibility of only wireless access causing the problem. It is most likely still an authentication issue, but sometimes process of elimination can help to narrow down the potential problems (such as an actual problem with the router or the router itself being blocked).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that cyperroam is not an ISP, but a firewall/network controller &/or router only. If you have a static ip it was most likely set by the dorms admins. If you know any of them you may want to run the issue by them, most don't have a problem with adding wireless as long as it is secured properly by a passphrase.

Comment: I don't know if the router sucks or what. If I just wanted to just transmit the connection that I arleady have (repeating), I should be able to do that. :\